# Find distance between two locations

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have two locations coordinates(Latitude and Longitude). I want to find the distance between them,but the output is wrong.

> **This is code**

```
   public static String distanceBetweenTwoPoint(double lng1, double lat1, double lng2, double lat2) {
    Location loc1 = new Location("Point A");
    loc1.setLatitude(lat1);
    loc1.setLongitude(lng1);

    Location loc2 = new Location("Point B");
    loc2.setLongitude(lng2);
    loc2.setLatitude(lat2);

    float distanceInMeter = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
    float distanceInKM = distanceInMeter / 1000;


    Log.v(TAG, "Distance in Meter: " + distanceInMeter + " | Distance in KM: " + distanceInKM);

    return String.valueOf(distanceInKM);


}
```

> The correct output is supposed to be equal **1.806 KM**
>
> The wrong output = **4771.8936 KM**

Answer (score 0):

What values are you passing to that function? And maybe the problem is the order. Perhaps `loc2.distanceTo(loc1)` gives you the distance the other way around, which seems to be the problem.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thank you for your interest and your response